# Can't install Windows Insider Preview on Lumia 530

Tags: update, insider-preview

I've been trying to get the Windows 10 Technical Preview on my Lumia 530, but after installing the Windows Insider app, selecting Insider Fast, then restarting, no updates are available according to phone update in settings, and the message "Your phone is up to date" is displayed. This has worked 3-4 months ago and now I can not get it to install again.

I am registered as an Insider, tried resetting my phone, reinstalling with the Recover Tool, and re-installing the Insider app, and still no success. I am at a loss for solutions.

Comment: How long have you given it? It can take up to a day for the build to show up.

Comment: It was running for a week after I set up the Insider app and still nothing,

Comment: This might be related to the "release" version of W10M (I consider it still more a beta than RC, much less RTM) being about to come out for legacy devices, but it's a strange event regardless. I trust you've hit the `[check for updates]` button on the phone?

Comment: @CBHacking Yes, multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has recently stated that "[they] do not have plans to put W10M on devices with 512 MB" [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://twitter.com/windowsinsider/status/710549849406513152) which - among other phones - also applies to Lumia 530.

In the past, insiders running 8.1 Denim had the GDR2 update rolled out to them through the insider app, which is a prerequisite for installing Windows 10 Mobile. Since that is no longer sent to unsupported phones, right now there's no way to update to an insider preview version from a fresh 8.1 install, at least not on a Lumia 530.

If you still have GDR2 you may be able to get insider builds up to a specific build number, but beyond that you won't be getting any more builds either. The only way to be able to use the latest Windows 10 Mobile OS if you have a 530 is to buy a new phone.